# Why is the Content Header 'application/javascript' causing a 500 Error?

Tags: php, iis-7, mime-types

I have a script that works fine on my test server (using IIS6). The script processes an ajax request and sends a response with the following line:

```
header( 'application/javascript' );
```

But on my live server, this line crashes the page and causes a 500 error.

Do I need to allow PHP to send different MIME types in IIS7? If so, how do I do this? I can't find any way on the interface.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The header is incorrect, try this instead:

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

Answer (score 3):

take a look at **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type**

There it says you should use application/javascript instead of text/javascript.